# Same eigenvalues, different eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm interested in the case of a specific matrix having different eigenvectors corresponding to two identical eigenvalues. The method I use for spectral decomposition returns different eigenvectors, even though the eigenvalue is the same. Is this possible, and if so, what this tells about the matrix?

Comment: Any vector is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ for the identity matrix.  All eigenvectors with a given eigenvalue form a linear space, so there will never be just one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Of course it's possible: 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2&0\\ 0&2
\end{bmatrix}
\,
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
=
2\;\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 0
\end{bmatrix},
\ \ \ \ \ \ 
\begin{bmatrix}
2&0\\ 0&2
\end{bmatrix}
\,
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
=
2\;\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

What it tells you about the matrix is that the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue is greater than $1$.

Comment: What do you mean by geometric multiplicity? How is different from algebraic multiplicity?

Comment: *(four years later; I don't know why I didn't reply back then)*. Geometric multiplicity for an eigenvalue is the dimension of its corresponding eigenspace. Algebraic multiplicity is the order of the eigenvalue as a root of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: I believe the question was whether 2 linear transformations T,T', could have equal eigenvalues,  but different Eigenvectors.  Even if it wasn't, can you please answer it.

Comment: Yes, of course. Consider $$\begin{bmatrix} 2&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad \begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}. $$ Both have eigenvalues $0$ and $2$, but the eigenvectors of the first one are (scalar multiplies of) $$\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix},\qquad \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\end{bmatrix},$$ while the second one has eigenvectors (scalar multiples of) $$\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\end{bmatrix},\qquad \begin{bmatrix} 1\\-1\end{bmatrix}.$$ More generally, $T$ and $STS^{-1}$ have the same eigenvalues for any invertible $S$.

Answer (score 3):

**A trivial example:** Consider the 2 by 2 identity matrix. It has only one eigenvalue, namely 1. However both $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$ are eigenvectors of this matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Quick test for a $2 \times 2$ matrix where $a$ are (same) eigenvalues:

\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & a\end{bmatrix}.

If $b = 0$, there are $2$ different eigenvectors for same eigenvalue $a$.

If $b \neq 0$, then there is only one eigenvector for eigenvalue $a$.

Answer (score 2):

Every eigenvalue with multiplicity = n will be associated with n different (as in linearly independent) eigenvalues.

Multiplicity is how many "times" it shows up as an eigenvalue. It is like when you find only one solution to a second degree equation, which always has two roots. This solution has a multiplicity = 2.